# Show pdf Android 11 kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

tengo problemas al visualizar un documento pdf ubicado en mi directorio Descargas.
Este es mi código, y me abre un directorio interno, pero yo quiero abrir automáticamente el pdf, sin pasar por la selección de archivos en el directorio.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
  addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
  type = "application/pdf"
  putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, Uri.fromFile(file))
}
startActivity(activity, intent, null)
```

Gracias, un saludo

---

gracias por responder @FranqoBalsamo, tengo un Try{}Catch
Me descargo el pdf asi,

```
val resolver = activity.contentResolver
val contentValues = ContentValues()
contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME, + nombrePdfDescargado + ".pdf")
contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.MIME_TYPE, "files/pdf")
contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.SIZE, filePath.size)
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

Y utilizo File asi

```
val file = File(File.separator + nombrePdfDescargado +".pdf")
val imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
fos = resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri)!!)!!
fos.write(filePath)

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
type = "application/pdf"
putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, Uri.fromFile(file))
            }
startActivity(activity, intent, null)
```

No se que me falta o que utilizo mal.. Quiero visualizarlo con Adobe, que en este caso si lo tengo instalado.
Espero su respuesta, muchas gracias de antemano.
Un saludo

Comment: Primero tendrías que tener un Try/Catch para captar las excepciones, segundo deberías tener un if/else para consultar sobre si hay (o no) una app para abrir el archivo con esa extensión. Tercero, ¿file es la ruta y el nombre del archivo? Cuarto, ¿Cómo quieres visualizar ese archivo, con adobe, con un navegador? Etc

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo gracias